# How to Auto-Accept Chats while permitting Cases to be Declined in Omni

Tags: email2case, chat, omnichannel, case-object

I'm trying to set up a means for allowing users to accept or decline an email-to-case while auto-assigning them live chats. The issue is that I can only seem to have one Presence Configuration assigned to a user/profile at a time. This makes sense, as you can't have two conflicting configurations for the same person.

However, the issue is that I cannot seem to set up a separate configuration between case and chat routing. The Chat Agent Configuration settings does not seem to have an option for Auto-Accepting chats if they are available on omni. This also makes sense, as this is not an Omnichannel setting, rather a chat-specific setting.

That brings me back to the same problem where I cannot seem to configure a presence configuration in Omni that's specific to Chat or Cases. Is there some other way I can allow for Presence configs to differentiate beyond just the user so that they may be assigned based on what's being routed through Omni (case/chat)?

I've seen this use-case before, though I don't know how it was implemented. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question. I did not notice that there is configuration for Auto Accepting Chats in the Chat Button and Invitations settings. This resolves the issue.